Can an application sending Zipkin data to Jaeger backend be configured to send the data to Tempo instead?
I have an application currently instrumented with OpenTracing (the famous 'sock-shop' application - https://github.com/microservices-demo - which is now deprecated) and configured to send trace data in Zipkin format to a Jaeger backend. This setup involves:
The application uses OpenTracing with the zipkin-go-opentracing library to send data to a Jaeger backend via Zipkin API (port 9411).
Jaeger is deployed with its COLLECTOR_ZIPKIN_HOST_PORT environment variable set to accept Zipkin format data.
Now, I want to explore switching the backend from Jaeger to Grafana Tempo for managing traces, while still not editing the application code(which is now written with opentracing library)
Here are my questions:
Can Tempo accept Zipkin-formatted data directly from an application instrumented with OpenTracing?
If yes, what configuration changes are required in the application or in Tempo to make this work?
